# Unity Augmenter Reality on Android with Video playing

Tags: unity, android, augmented-reality

Hey sisters and brothers,
So, I created an augmented reality marker, which works perfectly, I was able to display 3 shape on the screen with my Nexus 5.

I would like to replace my shapes with a Video. So, when the user track on the marker, I would like to start to play a video above the marker as a part of the augmented reality (No full screen playing).

I tried to use this video tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBc3ubr18ks) , but on Android you can't use MovieTexture (they say).

My question(s): how can I display a shape above the marker, with a video on it and what it the video format ? When I trying to build the project with mp4, it failing, but when I do with AVI it's okay, but the app crashing.

Thank you,

Answer (score -1):

I did not test this, but I think this should also work with vuforia, since Unity has this Video Textures http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MovieTexture.html . So you could simply assign your video as texture to an object which is assigned to the marker.

Answer (score -1):

Use the video playback unity package sample  from vuforia website.